# custom shape in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, custom-controls

I want to derive Shape class following:

```
class MyRectangle : Shape
{
    protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```

but I get error because DefiningGeometry property can't be overrided (althought wpf can). 
How can i custom shape in WP8 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should base your custom shape on a [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) rather than inheriting from `Shape` directly.

Comment: Can you add more info ? How can I do this ?