# How can I use the DefiningGeometry property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8

I am porting a WPF solution to WindowsPhone.

I know this property from `System.Windows.Shapes` [exist on Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.defininggeometry(v=vs.110).aspx).

My problem is that I added a `using System.Windows.Shapes;`, but I still cant access to it. If I open `System.Windows.Shapes`, I cant see it.

I think that I didnt have the right assembly (PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)).

I am not [the first one to ask](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/2a2a173c-0a84-4f9e-849d-347a96715514/custom-shape-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop). If I really can do it. Can I do an equivalent ?

Just found a [kind of duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519936/custom-shape-in-windows-phone-8) in SO. The answer didnt solve the issue, but it can be a start.

How can I achieve this ?

(I got the same problem with PresentationCore, but I managed to dodge it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefiningGeometry is a protected property, that's why you cannot access it.

After the shape was rendered, you can use the RenderedGeometry, but I don't know if you can trust that property.

Another option is to check what type of geometry do you have, cast it and convert it manually.

**Edit**

Using the RenderedGeometry:

```
Geometry GetGeometry(Shape shape)
{
    return shape.RenderedGeometry;
}
```

Casting it manually:

```
Geometry GetGeometry(Shape shape)
{
    Rectangle rectangle = shape as Rectangle;
    if (rectangle != null)
    {
       return new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), rectangle.RadiusX, rectangle.RadiusY, rectangle.GeometryTransform);
    }

    Ellipse ellipse = shape as Ellipse;
    if (ellipse != null)
    {
       //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

As I see in MSDN, besides the example code for Rectangle I wrote below, you have to write a similar code for: Rectangle, Ellipse, Line, Path, Polygon and Polyline.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx#inheritanceContinued